# Stack groups in a DataFrame on top of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas df with duplicate indices and a single column:

```
        value    
1     0.996957  
1     1.098198  
1     1.184518  
2     1.255916  
2     1.312393
```

What I want to do is to obtain a df with the unique indices, and the different values that each index takes as columns. The last column of the df would depend on the index which appears the most amount of times.

So for this example I'd want:

```
       1          2         3
1   0.996957   1.098198  1.184518 
2   1.255916   1.312393    NaN
```

What I've done so far works, but can surely be improved grouping by the index and somehow building the new df through the groups:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.arange(df.groupby(df.index)\
                .count().value.max()))
for i in np.unique(df.index.values):
    data_points_i = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[i,:].value.values).transpose()
    data = pd.concat([data,data_points_i], axis = 0)
data.index = df.index.unique()
```

Where df is the original df and data the one I end up with. Any help on optimizing this piece of code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `pd.Series` show up again

```
df.groupby(level=0).value.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
Out[630]: 
          0         1         2
1  0.996957  1.098198  1.184518
2  1.255916  1.312393       NaN
```

Let me do it `pivot`

```
df.assign(New=df.value.groupby(df.index).cumcount()).reset_index().pivot('index','New','value')
Out[635]: 
New           0         1         2
index                              
1      0.996957  1.098198  1.184518
2      1.255916  1.312393       NaN
```

Comment: @AlexandreNixon yw : -)

Comment: No, not again :|

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ adding a pivot one ! finally

Answer (score 3):

#### `set_index` + `unstack`

```
df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).unstack()['value']
              
          0         1         2
1  0.996957  1.098198  1.184518
2  1.255916  1.312393       NaN
```